# Netlogo: Nested if/ifelse statements

Tags: if-statement, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

Building my first ABM using Netlogo and have a problem involving ifelse statements and how to use them. I'm modelling agents response to flooded properties. The concepts are as follows:

If an agent is flooded, they will consider adopting protective measures (if they haven't already).
If an agent has adopted protective measures, and are flooded, the success of the measure is calculated.

My code is as follows:

```
    to process-property
  let $random-flood-number random-float 1
  ask properties [
    set flood-damage-list-consequent replace-item 1 flood-damage-list-consequent (item 1 flood-damage-list-initial * (1 - PLP-reduction))
    set flood-damage-list-consequent replace-item 2 flood-damage-list-consequent (item 2 flood-damage-list-initial * (1 - PLP-reduction))'
    ifelse $random-flood-number < probability-flooding
    [
      set flooded? TRUE
      set number-of-times-flooded (number-of-times-flooded + 1)
      if plp-adopted? != TRUE [
        calculate-adoption-intention
      ]
    ]
    [
      set flooded? FALSE
    ]
  ]

  ask properties with [plp-adopted? = TRUE] [
    plp-reliability-analysis
  ]

end

    to plp-reliability-analysis
  if plp-abandoned? = TRUE [stop]
  if flooded? = TRUE [
  if number-of-times-flooded > 1 [
    let plp-reliability-factor 0.77 ;;This variable represents the probability of success that Manual PLP will offer full reduction in damage. Taken from JBA (2012;2014).
    ifelse random-float 1 < plp-reliability-factor
      [
        set plp-deployed-successful? TRUE
        set PLP-reduction 0.25
        set successful-flood-damage-reduction (sum flood-damage-list-initial * PLP-reduction)
      ]
      [
        set plp-deployed-successful? FALSE
        set PLP-reduction 0.9
        set unsuccessful-flood-damage-reduction (sum flood-damage-list-initial * PLP-reduction)
        calculate-abandonment-intention
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

I have written the following code as an error check, which i keep getting:

```
if flooded? = FALSE and plp-deployed-successful? = TRUE [error["Properties should only deploy PLP when they are flooded"]]
```

I believe the problem lies in the ifelse statements in "plp-reliability-analysis" procedure. I'm new to Netlogo and am confused as to when to use an 'if' or 'ifelse' statement. If someone could explain and have a look at the above code i'd be very grateful.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `if` and `ifelse` is that:

- `if` is used when you want to run some piece of code only under certain conditions
- `ifelse` is used when you want to run some piece of code under some condition and a different piece of code if the condition is not met.

Have a look at this shortened version of your code. Note that I moved the opening bracket to the beginning of the line to line up the start and end of code blocks. I also put end bracket on the same line for very short code blocks, but the bracketing is the same as yours.

```
to process-property
  let $random-flood-number random-float 1
  ask properties
  [ ifelse $random-flood-number < probability-flooding
    [ set flooded? TRUE ]
    [ set flooded? FALSE ]
  ]
  ask properties with [plp-adopted? = TRUE]
  [ plp-reliability-analysis
  ]
end

to plp-reliability-analysis
  if flooded? = TRUE
  [ if number-of-times-flooded > 1
    [ let plp-reliability-factor 0.77
      ifelse random-float 1 < plp-reliability-factor
      [ set plp-deployed-successful? TRUE ]
      [ set plp-deployed-successful? FALSE ]
    ]
  ]
end
```

You draw a random number and assign it to the variable $random-flood-number. Then you ask every property agent to compare that number to the value of `probability-flooding`. However, you never draw a new random number. So if it's true for one property, it will be true for all the properties. Given it is a flood model, that is presumably intentional as all houses are equally affected by flooding.

Imagine that a low number is drawn and they all get flooded. All the ones with plp-adopted? are then sent to the plp-reliability-analysis procedure. For all of them, the variable flooded? is true so the code block is run.

The first line is `if number-of-times-flooded > 1`. The first time a flood occurs, the number-of-times-flooded is changed from 0 to 1. That will fail the test (did you mean to use >= instead of > ?) and the remainder of the code will not be run. It will simply jump to the end bracket.

```
[ let plp-reliability-factor 0.77
  ifelse random-float 1 < plp-reliability-factor
  [ set plp-deployed-successful? TRUE ]
  [ set plp-deployed-successful? FALSE ]
]
```

But for the second and later code, it will run and 77% of the properties will have the plp recorded as successful, and the others set to unsuccessful.

So, how do you end up with some properties having the combination of false flood? and true plp-deployed-successful?.

Now jump forward in time and 2 (or more) floods have occurred. A flood has just happened, so 77% of the properties with plp-adopted? have true plp-deployed-successful? This time, there is not a flood and all properties have flooded? set to false. Those with plp-adopted? are sent to the plp-reliability-analysis procedure. However, flooded? is now false so the code block does not run and they retain their values of plp-deployed-successful? from the previous run through.

Comment: Each patch that properties lie on have different values for probability-flooding, so based on the random number drawn, some properties may be flooded and others may not. plp-reliability-factor does not represent 77% of properties, rather it is the success rate of plp. So, if a random number is > that 0.77, it is unsuccessful. I understand what you mean about retaining their values of plp-deployed-successful? TRUE. If a property is adopted, yet not flooded, how do I ensure that the property does not try and calculate whether plp-deployed-successful? is TRUE/FALSE

Comment: (1) ok, different properties may have different values but you are still only drawing one random number. If you draw a low random number, lots of properties will flood and if you draw a high random number then no properties will flood. (2) If a variable is only supposed to operate for a single tick, then just set it to false as the last thing you do before the `tick` command.